# Iframe con http y parent con https, rechaza el contenido siendo el mismo dominio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy metiendo un iframe de forma dinámica en un div,y tiene que cargar un contenido HTTP con una ruta local (http://192.168...). Esta es la función.

```
function pasteIframe() {
    let ifrm = document.createElement('iframe'); 
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://192.168.98.120:51285'); 
    ifrm.className = 'ifr';

    let div = presenter.$view.find('.addon1');
    $(ifrm).appendTo(div);
}
```

Lo inserto en el div correspondiente pero me aparece este mensaje:

> Se ha bloqueado la carga del contenido activo mixto
>   "http://192.168.98.120:51285/"

El dominio donde está alojada la web principal tiene protocolo HTTPS y el contenido del iframe es HTTP, porque así es la ruta interna.

¿Cómo puedo cargar dicho contenido?

Comment: Si los puertos son distintos, entonces el navegador considera que son dos dominios distintos

Comment: Dentro del mismo dominio, con la misma ruta de directorios y servidor, el iframe puede tener distinto puerto que el 'parent'?

Comment: Como te he comentado, si el puerto no es exactamente el mismo, no es el mismo dominio

Comment: Curioso, cómo puedo averiguarlo? Enviando mensajes con 'postMessage'?